# saving a value from another table in a oracle trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-trigger

I'm writting a trigger and I'm crushing with a wall, 'cause I need to save a value from another table in a variable, and then substract that value to a column of another table, I'm working with a trigger but it doesn't work :(

This is my code:

```
create or replace trigger tg_update_total_new_product
after insert on detalle_comanda 
for each row
declare
    var_precio numeric;
begin
    var_precio := (select precio from producto where id=:new.producto_id);
     update comanda set precuenta=precuenta+var_precio where id=:new.comanda_id;
END;
```

The error code is the next:

```
Trigger TG_UPDATE_TOTAL_NEW_PRODUCT compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/20      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat
4/73      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem    <an exponent (**)> and or group having intersect minus order    start union where connect || indicator multiset 
6/4       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable persistable order    overriding static member constructor map 
Errors: check compiler log
```

That table is a middle-one, then I have the total of the sale in another table, and I want that, when someone add a product, the total is added... I've been thinking in a function, or a view, but I don't know why this isn't working...
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use SELECT ... INTO ...:

```
select precio into var_precio from producto where id=:new.producto_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using any variable as you will need to handle no data found, more than one rows fetched exception. You can directly use the `SELECT` statement inside the `UPDATE` statement as follows:

```
create or replace trigger tg_update_total_new_product
after insert on detalle_comanda 
for each row
begin
     update command 
        set precuenta=precuenta 
                      + COALESCE((select precio from producto where id=:new.producto_id),0) 
      where id=:new.comanda_id;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you have made a mistake - `var_precio := (select precio from producto where id=:new.producto_id);`

You have to use select [column] into [variable]

Therefore, your correct syntax should be -

```
select precio into var_precio from producto where id=:new.producto_id;
```